# Does Twilio support threaded conversations in a chat app?

Tags: twilio-programmable-chat

We are building a chat app where we want to support threaded conversation to maintain context just like popular apps like Slack or Discord. Does Twilio chat APIs support that?

I did find a reference to this in their documents but not enough details for how best to manage this in our app.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box Twilio Chat doesn't support any form of threaded conversation.

This would require a custom implementation that will vary depending on the use case but could use the `attributes` property of messages to maintain a context to compare against. For example, messages may contain an attribute `"parentId"` that allows you to identify related content, this may be an ID you generate or the SID's produced by Twilio.